# Regression dummy*Likert scale

Tags: regression, stata, interaction

I have a problem with an interaction, which I want to integrate in my ols regression model. The dependent variable is a 5 point Likert scale; the independent variables are a dummy variable and another 5 point Likert scale variable. Besides that I want to have an interaction between those independent variables in the model. The code i use is

reg "depvar" "indep_dummy"##"indep_likert"

As far as I know this should include the main effects of both variables and the interaction between them. Sadly Stata treats the independent Likert scale variable as a categorical variable instead of an ordinal scaled. How can I fix this?

I know that I can put a `c.` in front of the independent variables to treat them as continuous but does that work for ordinal variables?

Comment: What would treating a predictor as ordinal look like? Stata offers `c.` and `i.` for continuous and categorical variables in factor variable notation. Those are the choices. You're already treating your outcome (independent variable) as if it were continuous. `help fvvarlist` leads to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I was just unsure if i had to treat the ordinal variable as continuous. But i also just read that STATA treats the nondefined variables in such interactions always as categorial. When i define the variable with "c." it results in the same coefficient as if  would generate a faktorvariable by myself so i think that was it.

Again Thank you wery much!

Comment: Other way round. `i.` flags treat as factor variable.